# Unable to create a beautiful url with HTACCESS

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

What I am trying to do is shorten this url:
example.com?controller=iphone&action=xyz

into:

example.com/iphone/xyz

This is what I tried which isn't working:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Rikesh index.php should stay in the htaccess, it's where the routing script resides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no obvious need to require the trailing slash in your pattern, nor limit it to finish immediately after with the line ending `$` either. Note also I changed `*` to `+` because you'd almost certainly want both controller and action to be at least one character long.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating on how your code differs from his, and why yours would work while his won't.

Comment: @AmitGarg Thanks its working!. but what if I want it also to pass other arguments? for example: http://example.com/iphone/action?parameter1=1&parameter2=2 If im trying to access that link it won't pass the parameters

Comment: @DanRevah then you need the [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: This isn't likely to work if there are more than 2 path segments. E.g. "/a/b/c"

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]